# Shell script for moving images to new folder based on list provided

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, applescript

I am working on script where I have the list of imagesnames in txt file. It has total 2000 images names listed and every image has .png extensions. I have source folder which has around 6000 images.

My requirement is write the script that copy a image from source folder to destination (New) folder. Script will take image name one by one from txt file. I tried various approach but it didn't worked out.

If you won't get my question comment on this I will elaborate.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an extract of the `.txt` list?

Comment: I have edited my question. Above is my txt file which has images listed.

Comment: You say *to destination (New) folder which is listed in txt file*.  But where is the new folder supposed to be found?

Comment: I mean destination folder would be new folder where I want to copy all these images. It has not yet  created. Either we create it through script or we can created it manually before to run script.

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
$ mkdir newFolder
$ <fileList.txt xargs -n 1 -I {} cp {} sourceFolder newFolder
```

should do, if I understand the question.  Here we use the handy `xargs` command, which builds and execute commands based on its input.

In other words, we are building and executing a

```
$ cp item.png sourceFolder newFolder
```

for each `item.png` in the file list, the `{}` acting as placeholder.

Comment: or `xargs -a fileList.txt ...`